# MySQL - using a prepared statement to copy a row in the same table and include static values throws an error

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a prepared statement to copy one row to a new row (INSERT)in the same table and include some static values. However, I get the following error:

```
SQLException in copyProgram: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

My input is:

```
prId: 4 accountID: 50 newFromDate: 2020-04-27 newToDate: 2020-04-28
```

My code is:

```
    String insertQry = ("INSERT INTO at_program "
            + "(acc_id, pr_name, pr_start_date, pr_start_time, pr_end_date, pr_end_time, "
            + "pr_cost_pp, pr_woodbeads, pr_special, pr_joeys, pr_cubs, "
            + "pr_scouts, pr_venturers, pr_rovers, pr_leaders, pr_family, "
            + "pr_swimming, pr_pioneering, pr_archery, pr_canoe, pr_bushwalking, "
            + "pr_4wd, pr_abseiling, pr_snorkelling, pr_boating, "
            + "pr_rock_climbing, pr_caving, pr_branch_instructions, pr_policies_information, "
            + "pr_whs, pr_other, pr_notes) "
            + " (SELECT (?, pr_name, ?, pr_start_time, ?, pr_end_time, "
                    + "pr_cost_pp, pr_woodbeads, pr_special, pr_joeys, pr_cubs, "
                    + "pr_scouts, pr_venturers, pr_rovers, pr_leaders, pr_family, "
                    + "pr_swimming, pr_pioneering, pr_archery, pr_canoe, pr_bushwalking, "
                    + "pr_4wd, pr_abseiling, pr_snorkelling, pr_boating, "
                    + "pr_rock_climbing, pr_caving, pr_branch_instructions, pr_policies_information, "
                    + "pr_whs, pr_other, pr_notes) "
            + " FROM at_program "
            + " WHERE pr_id = ?);"); 

 ps = c.prepareStatement(insertQry, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            // Create a statement and execute the query on it               
            ps.setString(1, accountID);
            ps.setString(2, fromDate);
            ps.setString(3, toDate);
            ps.setString(4, prID);

            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: it is enouf ti delete the ( in the SELECT (? so it is (SELECT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parens around the field list in your `SELECT`! Remove them.

The issue is that `SELECT` expects a list of (individual) columns, but you are passing a multi-column value.

`SELECT x, y, z` sees `x`, `y` and `z` as three values each consisting of one column, yet you are passing `SELECT (x, y, z)` which is interpreted as *one* value with *three* columns, hence the error.

By the way, the parens around the whole `SELECT` are superfluous as well, this time because `INSERT INTO table (columns) SELECT ...` is a recognized syntax construct in itself.

Corrected code:

```java
    String insertQry = ("INSERT INTO at_program "
            + "(acc_id, pr_name, pr_start_date, pr_start_time, pr_end_date, pr_end_time, "
            + "pr_cost_pp, pr_woodbeads, pr_special, pr_joeys, pr_cubs, "
            + "pr_scouts, pr_venturers, pr_rovers, pr_leaders, pr_family, "
            + "pr_swimming, pr_pioneering, pr_archery, pr_canoe, pr_bushwalking, "
            + "pr_4wd, pr_abseiling, pr_snorkelling, pr_boating, "
            + "pr_rock_climbing, pr_caving, pr_branch_instructions, pr_policies_information, "
            + "pr_whs, pr_other, pr_notes) "
            + " SELECT ?, pr_name, ?, pr_start_time, ?, pr_end_time, "
                    + "pr_cost_pp, pr_woodbeads, pr_special, pr_joeys, pr_cubs, "
                    + "pr_scouts, pr_venturers, pr_rovers, pr_leaders, pr_family, "
                    + "pr_swimming, pr_pioneering, pr_archery, pr_canoe, pr_bushwalking, "
                    + "pr_4wd, pr_abseiling, pr_snorkelling, pr_boating, "
                    + "pr_rock_climbing, pr_caving, pr_branch_instructions, pr_policies_information, "
                    + "pr_whs, pr_other, pr_notes "
            + " FROM at_program "
            + " WHERE pr_id = ?;");
```